# Difference between Generic Interrupt Controller and Nested Vectored Interrupt controller

Tags: arm

I saw that Cortex A9 supports a GIC. How is it different from NVIC?

Are these two mutually exclusive? Meaning if GIC exists the NVIC does not?

please share your thoughts

Comment: The NVIC is typcially for Cortex-M and GIC for Cortex-A.  The GIC is structured for an AXI bus with multi-cpu.  The NVIC is AHB with a single CPU.  They are not 'mutually exclusive'. For instance, the [AMP-Vybrid](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/homepage.jsp?code=VYBRID) has both.  You question is rather broad and not really on topic, imo.  If you ask specifics about the controller, it seem more suited to StackOverflow.  The standard Cortex-A9 comes bundled with a GIC-390; there are different versions.  A vendor is free to do what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the answers

**Are these two mutually exclusive? Meaning if GIC exists the NVIC does not?**

Yes. Your understanding is correct.

**Why?**
Any processor/core can support only one interrupt controller. Because HW will become more complex if we have two interrupt controller and it is not feasible.

GIC has more feature and multicore support you can check below link for more information

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/198123/latest